# R crashes after I try to load a heavy tif file

Tags: r, raster, tiff, filesize

I am trying to load a large, multi-layer `tif` file in R, but it keeps crashing.  I am using R 4.2.2 on RStudio 2022.12.0.353.  My sample code is the following.

```
library(tiff)
library(raster)

y <- 1985

url <- paste0("https://storage.googleapis.com/mapbiomas-public/brasil/collection-7/lclu/coverage/brasil_coverage_",y,".tif")

file <- paste0("C:/Dropbox/projetos/mapbiomas/full/",basename(url))

download.file(url,file, mode = "wb")

raster <- tiff::readTIFF(file,all = T)
```

After I run the last line, my R session is aborted and terminated due to a "fatal error."  I understand that the `tif` file is heavy, and I imagine that there might be a way to open each band separately, but I could not find it.

Comment: Can you do `r <- raster(file)` without a crash? Better not to call your object `raster` as that's the name of a package you have loaded. It's also the name of the [`raster()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.5-29/topics/raster) function in that package that creates a raster layer from file or object.

Comment: Thank you.  It works.  For some reason, in previous sessions it was leading to the same error.  I am sorry for the lack of attention.

Answer (score 0):

Following [SamR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12545041/samr)'s comment, using

```
r <- raster(file)
```

works.